# How can I download youtube videos php?

Tags: php, video, download, youtube

I am looking for anyway to download video from youtube ...
Of course I used and tried all codes and scripts , all of them are failure ...

Therefore I want the new code that help me ...

Comment: post the code you have tried, we will start from there

Comment: Most people just use their browser to view the video, which downloads the .flv file to their computer... This falls under the "any way" you specify.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use an external tool for that. [`youtube-dl`](http://freshmeat.net/projects/youtube-dl) comes to mind, and is simple to utilize from within PHP:

```
$url = escapeshellcmd($url);
exec("youtube-dl $url -O /tmp/video.flv");
```

Comment: Then rewrite it in PHP if you want.

Comment: I tried install youtube-dl in server ... then I test this `root@ns1 
[~]# youtube-dl www.youtube.com/watch?v=62h6Wr7heXk
[youtube] Setting language
[youtube] 62h6Wr7heXk: Downloading video info webpage
[youtube] 62h6Wr7heXk: Extracting video information
ERROR: format not available for video`

Comment: You will have to update it to the latest version. Use `sudo youtube-dl -U` on the cmdline. http://www.ubuntugeek.com/howto-download-videos-from-youtube-in-ubuntu.html

Comment: @mario I have latest version ... and i reinstall it but it still not working ... my operation is : CentOs 5

Comment: but the problem when I do that : `root@ns1 [~]# sudo youtube-dl -U
usage: Usage: youtube-dl [options] url...

youtube-dl: error: no such option: -U`

Comment: I kindly refer you to my answer. There's the link. Download a contemporary version first. Then update as you were advised half an hour ago.

Comment: see this is the error when I update : `root@ns1 [~]# sh youtube-dl -U
import: unable to open X server `'.
import: unable to open X server `'.
import: unable to open X server `'.
import: unable to open X server `'.
import: unable to open X server `'.
import: unable to open X server `'.
import: unable to open X server `'.
import: unable to open X server `'.
import: unable to open X server `'.
import: unable to open X server `'.
import: unable to open X server `'.
import: unable to open X server `'.
import: unable to open X server `'.
import: unable to open X server `'.`

Comment: Are you trying to troll me? Where does the `sh` come from? Why not start it correctly?

Comment: sh is the alternative of sudo , because my operation is centos and the lesson is in Ubuntu .. I want the way to install it in CentOs

Comment: No, it's not. I don't understand why you can't just type in the same command as you did 20 minutes ago.

Comment: when I use sudo there get error ... therefore I use sh , but I think the error that no new package for CentoS

Comment: Well, then keep using `sh` instead of `sudo` (which is a standard Linux command and works under CentOS too). My free support ends here - since you only play dumb, make demands, and don't even have the courtesy to accept the answer.

Comment: this comment exchange is hilarious

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
 // The YouTube ID
 $key = "Ct5KJKBI9kc";
 // Get all info for video
 $output = file_get_contents('http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?&video_id='.$key);
 // Parse data to eg.(&id=var)
 parse_str($output);
 // Get Quality map of video an set array
if(isset($url_encoded_fmt_stream_map)) {
 $my_formats_array = explode(',',$url_encoded_fmt_stream_map);
} 
 // Set Array & Vars
 $avail_formats[] = '';
 $i = 0;
 // Break up array to create download links to quality
 foreach($my_formats_array as $format) {
 parse_str($format);
echo "<a download='". $title .".mp4' href='".$avail_formats[$i]['url'] = urldecode($url) . '&signature=' . $sig."'>". $title .".mp4</a> Quality - ".$quality."<br>"; $i++; } ?>
```

Comment: Just change the $key value to your youtube video id and run.

Comment: Regarding the use of `parse_str` in this code, php manual says: **Warning:** Using this function without second parameter is DISCOURAGED. Dynamically setting variables in function's scope suffers from exactly same problems as register_globals.

Comment: 2023: This www.youtube.com page can’t be found